# How does OSPF bind to multiple network interfaces?

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming, serversocket

The routing protocol OSPF has a configuration command as "network  " to help determine which network interface to operate on. And this command can be used to multiple times on different networks. My question is if this means the OSPF socket, or, raw socket, can bind to multiple addresses? Per my understanding, each socket has only one protocol control block(PCB), and each PCB has only one address.  I'm only looking for high level explanation. For example, if OSPF socket can have multiple PCBs, or, OSPF's PCB can have multiple addresses.

Comment: OSPF uses link-local multicast addresses: `224.0.0.5` All Routers and `224.0.0.6` Designated Routers.

Comment: Does it mean OSPF bind the multicast addresses to selected network interfaces?

Comment: Adding an interface to OSPF only means that OSPF will send hellos and try to contact another OSPF router on that interface. I think you are reading too much into it.

Comment: Say a router has three network interfaces in separate networks, and two of them are selected. Then when the OSPF multicasts advertisement from a socket, how does it figure out which interfaces to send advertisement from? Is it the OSPF creating two sockets, each of which is used to advertise, or, a single socket is used with two network interfaces bound?

Comment: OSPF uses its own protocol (IP protocol 89) directly in IP. It doesn't use TCP (IP protocol 6) or UDP (IP protocol 17), which have addresses, called ports, which are used when creating sockets. [Encapsulation of OSPF packets](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1583#appendix-A.1)

Comment: I understood OSPF uses raw socket. It still binds.

Comment: That depends on the OS and OSPF implementation. You can say it binds, or in pure networking OSes, it registers with the IP process running on particular ports. Basically, any IP protocol 89 packets are sent to an OSPF process which has registered with the IP process on a port are sent to the registered OSPF process. There can be significant differences in how this is done on a general purpose OS vs. a monolithic networking OS, where the routing processes are built in to the OS.

Comment: OK. I would just assume OSPF's raw socket is customized so it can bind to multiple IP addresses/network interfaces at a time.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the implementation.

You don't need customized sockets to use different interfaces and you don't need to work only with one socket. The implementation can use N raw sockets each one bound to one of N interfaces. Then the implementation can have one or N threads handling those N sockets.

Also it could use packet sockets but it doesn't make much sense.

Additionally it could use libpcap for receiving messages and sending messages.

Look at Quagga: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quagga_(software)